# Create new data frame with mean of multiple rows

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I have a dataframe consisting of three columns: ID, Trial and a difference measure (diff_DT). I have 19 participant, who completed 30 trials each. This is how my dataframe looks like:

```
    ID     Trial     diff_DT
    01      005       37,5
    01      006       40,5
    01      007       16,5
    ...     ...       ...
    02      005       16,5 
    ...     ...       ...
    02      016       27,9
```

Always six of the 30 trials belong to one block: block 1: trial 5-10, block 2: trial 16-21, block 3: trial 26-31, block 4: trial 36-41, block 5: trial 46-51 (Note: trial numbers are > 30, because participants completed more trials in total)

Now I need the mean of the variable diff_DT for each participant for each block, resulting in five means for each participant. And I have no idea how to do it properly. 
Thanks for your advices!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate key data frame or matrix for the blocks/trials, merge that to your original table, and then run aggregate to get the mean score.

```
 ID <- c(rep(1, 3), 2, 2)
 Trial <- c(5, 6, 7, 5, 16)
 diff_DT <- c(37.5, 40.5, 16.5, 16.5, 27.9)
 Trial.key <- c(5:10, 16:21, 26:31, 36:41, 46:51)
 block <- rep(1:5, each = 6)

 df <- data.frame(ID, Trial, diff_DT)
 blocks <- data.frame(Trial.key, block)

 df.blocks <- merge(df, blocks, by.x = "Trial", by.y = "Trial.key", all.x = TRUE,
                    all.y = FALSE)
 df.blocks
#  Trial ID diff_DT block
#     5  1    37.5     1
#     5  2    16.5     1
#     6  1    40.5     1
#     7  1    16.5     1
#    16  2    27.9     2

 df.agg <- with(df.blocks, aggregate(diff_DT, by = list(ID, Trial), 
                                     FUN = "mean"))
 names(df.agg) <- c("ID", "Trial", "mean.diff_DT")
 df.agg
#  ID Trial mean.diff_DT
#  1     5         37.5
#  2     5         16.5
#  1     6         40.5
#  1     7         16.5
#  2    16         27.9
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this will help you.

```
bd <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:6, each = 30),
             Trial = c(sample(c(5:10,16:21,26:31,36:41,46:51), 30), 
                       sample(c(5:10,16:21,26:31,36:41,46:51), 30),
                       sample(c(5:10,16:21,26:31,36:41,46:51), 30), 
                       sample(c(5:10,16:21,26:31,36:41,46:51), 30),
                       sample(c(5:10,16:21,26:31,36:41,46:51), 30), 
                       sample(c(5:10,16:21,26:31,36:41,46:51), 30)),
             diff_DT = rnorm(n = 180, mean = 30, sd = 2))

library(dplyr)
bd <- bd %>% 
  mutate(block = ifelse(Trial <= 10, 1, 
                    ifelse(Trial <= 21, 2, 
                           ifelse(Trial <= 31, 3,
                                  ifelse(Trial <= 41, 4, 5)))))
bd %>% 
group_by(ID, block) %>% 
summarise(Mean = mean(diff_DT))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only use base R, one way to do what you want is to create a column `block` in your dataframe and then apply the `mean` function for each participant in each block. 
If Trial is numeric (which may not be the case given that your trials are 001, 002...), you can

```
df$block = ifelse(df$trial>=5 & df$trial <=10, 1, 
              ifelse(df$trial>=16 & df$trial <=21,2,
              ifelse(df$trial>=26 & df$trial <=31,3,
              ifelse(df$trial>=36 & df$trial <=41,4,
              ifelse(df$trial>=46 & df$trial <=51,5,0))))
           )
```

if Trial is not numeric (eg. character or factor), you should first convert it to numeric with

```
df$trial = as.numeric(as.character(df$trial))
```

Then you just have to

```
aggregate(df$trial, by=list(df$block,df$id), mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this dataframe as an example (you should provide code for generating your data to make answering easier and more precise):

```
ID <- rep(1:3, 47)
trial <- rep(5:51, 3)
diff_DT <- sample(1:10, 47*3, replace = T)
df <- data.frame(ID, trial, diff_DT)
```

Then I wrote a function to compute blocks, the blocks are assigned like the ones you wrote in the question, if you need some precisation just ask:

```
computeBlocks <- function(df){
  block <- rep(NA, nrow(df))
  for(i in 1:length(block)){
    for(j in 1:4){
      if(as.numeric(df$trial[i]) >= 6+10*j && as.numeric(df$trial[i]) <= 11+10*j){
        block[i] <- j+1
        break
      }
    }
    if(as.numeric(df$trial[i]) >= 5 && as.numeric(df$trial[i]) <= 10){
      block[i] <- 1
    }
  }
  df <- cbind(df, block)
  return(df)
}
```

And I computed the blocks:

```
df <- computeBlocks(df)
```

Finally using the package `reshape2` I computed the mean per participant per block:

```
#install.packages("reshape2")
require(reshape2)
df_melt <- melt(df, id = c("ID", "block"))
means <- dcast(df_melt, ID + block ~ variable, mean)[,-3]
means
```

Your question wasn't so clear so let me know if it needs to be improved.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a simple way to do it:

```
library(dplyr)

# Create a table to map which Block each trial refers to 
Trial <- c(5:10,16:21,26:31,36:41,46:51)   
Block <- rep(1:5, each = 6)
map <- data_frame(Trial, Block)

# Take original data frame and join the map to add what Block it belongs to. Then group it first by participant ID, then Block, and summarise by mean
df2 <- df %>%
         left_join(map, by = "Trial") %>%
         group_by(ID, Block) %>%
         summarise(mean = mean(diff_DT))
```